# How to refresh an AsyncImage that is pointing to the same URL

Tags: swiftui

I have seen a lot of questions about AsyncImage and how to refresh it. In this case its a bit different. The image URL stays the same but the image will change periodically.
As such I was hoping to have a button to refresh it.

The problem is oldUrl == newURL.
I even tried some of the tricks where you set border color on a parent to try to trick SwiftUI to refresh it and none of that worked. For now I am manually showing and hiding the view to make this work. This is of course undesirable.

Might there be any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the image a new ID when the button is pressed. Example:

```
@State var id = UUID()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // this URL gives a random image every time you GET it
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300")!)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
            .id(id)
        Button("Update") {
            id = UUID()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice hack but probably has some memory overhead since it will be also recreating the underlying UIView objects